# Javascript sort function on dates not working

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

So I have this code -

```
console.log(data);
data = data.sort(function(d1,d2){
     var a1= d1["date"].split('/'), b1=d2["date"].split('/');
      if(a1[2]==b1[2]){
        return (a1[0]==b1[0])? a1[1]-b1[1]: a1[0]-b1[0];
      }
      return a1[2]-b1[2];
});
console.log("DATA");
console.log(data);
```

with this data -

```
[
{ "date": "2/7/2012", "quantity: " 4"},
{ "date": "2/4/2012", "quantity: "5"},
{ "date": "2/3/2012", "quantity: "10"},
{ "date": "2/5/2012", "quantity" : "12"},
{ "date": "2/6/2012", "quantity" : "10"}
]
```

The two console logs show the data in the same way, or the sorting has no effect. The data coming out of the sort function is in the same order as the data going in.

Why?

Comment: You're missing the closing quotes after `quantity`.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: That was after I fixed the quoting around some of the `quantity` properties.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
data = data.sort(function(d1,d2){
  return new Date(d1.date) - new Date(d2.date);
});
```

`DD/MM/YYYY` should be acceptable by Date parser, here is the spilt version.

```
data = data.sort(function(d1, d2){
  var d1 = d1.split('/'), d2 = d2.split('/');
  return new Date(d1[2], d1[0] - 1, d1[1]) - new Date(d2[2], d2[0] - 1, d2[1]);
});
```

Comment: His `date` properties aren't in a format that `new Date()` can parse portably.

Comment: Date parser is pretty lenient, it will still work. As long as all the dates are in the same format as your locale (in some places its day/month/year).

Comment: ok...but none of this explains why hte function above doesn't work

Comment: The Date parser is lenient, but different browsers understand different formats. The only format I think you can be sure will work is `YYYY-MM-DD`.